# Cannot completely dump Task Scheduler logs

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

I am working to exploit Task Scheduler logs to determine a timeline of jobs run at our site. Often we have to identify a job and we may only know the time the job failed. In such a case we begin searching servers and log files to find the job in question. To assist I've begun dumping logs and parsing them into a site timeline. It works well excepting task scheduler limits output with this message:

> There are no scheduled tasks presently available at your access level.

How do I elevate privileges to get all job logs?

This is a sponsored project so one of our engineers will implement a method that works. I have thought of a push mechanism where an admin would auto-dump logs and I'd copy and parse.

I dump logs with:

```
schtasks /S server /Query /FO TABLE /V /HRESULT
```

Running from an elevated shell does nothing more and using production account credentials does not either.

Answer (score 1):

If your account is that of an administrator, you could use [PsExec from SysInternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) to elevate your task to SYSTEM level, where all is permitted (but great care is required).